# How to get argument name in Matlab constructor

Tags: matlab, oop

I would like to get the input argument name within the constructor of a class much like below:

```matlab
classdef Task

    properties
        Name string
    end

    methods
        function this = Task(callback)
            arguments
                callback {isFunctionCallSignal}
            end

            this.Name = inputname(1);
        end
    end

end
```

Which I use like so:

```matlab
task = Task(@hello_world)
```

where `@hello_world` is a function call signal to an existing function.

How can I get the `task.Name` to be of value `"hello_world"` upon instantiation? If if isn't possible within a constructor, is there another way I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In this example, calling `task = Task(@hello_world)` results in `task.Name = ""` because the function handle is not really a valid input to `inputname`. What's your expected behaviour here, that `task.Name = "hello_world"`? Or that your "Name" property is actually the function handle itself?

Comment: The goal is to have `task.Name = "hello_world"`. I clarified the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think for this case, you don't care about the *name* of the variable that was used as an input argument (which in this case doesn't exist because your input argument is simply an expression `@hello_world` rather than a variable).

I think what you want here is [`func2str`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/func2str.html):

```matlab
this.Name = ['@', func2str(callback)];
```

JFTR, `inputname` is for cases like this:

```matlab
myCallback = @hello_world;
task = Task(myCallback); % here, inputname returns 'myCallback'
```

In general, `inputname` is not a terribly useful function outside of cases where you're trying to implement object display. (Although there are [better ways these days](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.mixin.customdisplay-class.html?s_tid=doc_ta))

Answer (score 3):

If you want to store the actual function name i.e. `task.Name = 'hello_world'` then you need to use something like

```
this.Name = func2str( callback );
```

Note that if you include arguments in your anonymous function handle then they will be part of the output from `func2str`

```
func2str( @hello_world ) % = 'hello_world'
func2str( @(x) hello_world(x) ) % = '@(x)hello_world(x)'
```

If you want to store the actual function handle itself then you can just use `this.Name = callback;`.

`inputname` pulls in the variable name assigned to your input variable in the caller workspace. Since you're not using a variable (you're just dynamically inputting a value, albeit that value is a function handle) you'll see that `inputname` outputs `""`. You would have to do something like this to make use of `inputname`:

```
func_handle = @hello_world;
task = Task( func_handle ); % inside constructor, inputname(1) = "func_handle"
```